# Date filtering of array of objects with timestamps [chart added]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to feed a linear chart with a simple array [0,1,2,...] representing sums of `amount` divided by days. The input array has a complex structure, so my first take on it was as follows:

```js
const data = [{
    LQsZ2cuD1n5U10Rhg9p: {
      amount: 140,
      timestamp: 1541768493811
    }
  },
  {
    LR6Bx6pih4TRID9i3LW: {
      amount: 240,
      timestamp: 1542014096044
    }
  },
  {
    LR6IbF4Q0SI9TZ6Sh5h: {
      amount: 340,
      timestamp: 1542015841476
    }
  },
  {
    LR6NLdgGd2UgTMpnYYE: {
      amount: 460,
      timestamp: 1542017084204
    }
  },
  {
    LR6R5ql8lJW_gTctXB6: {
      amount: 110,
      timestamp: 1542018068191
    }
  },
  {
    LR6R5v0ag8twyTjeupC: {
      amount: 120,
      timestamp: 1542018068351
    }
  },
  {
    LR6R5xZZ4VNCIud71MP: {
      amount: 160,
      timestamp: 1542018069574
    }
  },
  {
    LR6R5zz5QrvrM_RTrvT: {
      amount: 310,
      timestamp: 1542018069716
    }
  },
  {
    LR6R6Aser7lmvrGetzm: {
      amount: 210,
      timestamp: 1542018069996
    }
  },
]

function getReduced(index) {
  const y = Object.values(data).map(e => Object.values(e))
    .map(e => Object.values(e)[0])
    .map(e => [Math.round((Date.now() - e.timestamp) / 8.64e7), e.amount])
    .filter(e => e[0] === index).map(e => e[1]);
  if (y === undefined) return 0;
  else return y.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}

const info = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].map((e, i) => getReduced(i++));
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = info;

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Today","1 day ago","2 days ago","3 days ago","4 days ago","5 days ago","6 days ago","A week ago","8 days ago","9 days ago","10 days ago","11 days ago",],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Money earned',
            data: info,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 3
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<div>Final array for feeding my chart: [<span id="info"></span>]</div>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

It kinda works, I've been struggling for several hours already but I am pretty sure there is a more clever and concise way to handle such situations where you want to quickly sort and sum array values depending on your time needs.
Yep, that final [0,1...] is lame as hell, doing this I tried to execute the function 11 times as my chart goes for last 11 days (Array(11) didn't work out for some reason, values were empty).

**Please help me to KO this ugly m*ker!**

EDIT: Have added the desired chart for getting the idea. There might be days without earnings. The chart always shows last 11 days, so the time window will be sliding every days leaving non-relevant values off the chart.

Comment: Not entirely clear what *"sums of amount divided by days"* means. What are expected results from data sample shown?

Comment: Objects are {amount:X, timestamp:Y}. To sum all amounts within a day, repeat for other days.

Comment: The time period starts with a day represented by timestamp and ends with timestamp of the following object?

Comment: @HynekS I count days like this `Math.round((Date.now() - e.timestamp) / 8.64e7`. When invoking a function I then filter the new array of `[day, amount]` with by a specific day index.

Comment: @HynekS that `Math.round` gives how many days passed since that specific object `{amount:X, timestamp:Y}` was created relatively to current day. Finally it would be a simple chart with accumulated amounts for last 11 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you could use a single [**`reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```js
const data = [{ LQsZ2cuD1n5U10Rhg9p: { amount: 14, timestamp: 1541768493811 } }, { LR6Bx6pih4TRID9i3LW: { amount: 24, timestamp: 1542014096044 } }, { LR6IbF4Q0SI9TZ6Sh5h: { amount: 34, timestamp: 1542015841476 } }, { LR6NLdgGd2UgTMpnYYE: { amount: 46, timestamp: 1542017084204 } }, { LR6R5ql8lJW_gTctXB6: { amount: 11, timestamp: 1542018068191 } }, { LR6R5v0ag8twyTjeupC: { amount: 12, timestamp: 1542018068351 } }, { LR6R5xZZ4VNCIud71MP: { amount: 16, timestamp: 1542018069574 } }, { LR6R5zz5QrvrM_RTrvT: { amount: 31, timestamp: 1542018069716 } }, { LR6R6Aser7lmvrGetzm: { amount: 21, timestamp: 1542018069996 } }, ]

const group = arr => arr.reduce((r,c) => {
  let key = Object.keys(c)[0], date = Math.round((Date.now() - c[key].timestamp) / 864e5)
  r[date] += c[key].amount
  return r
}, new Array(11).fill(0))

console.log(group(data)) //(11) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 195, 0, 0, 14]
```

The idea is to start with pre-filled array of 0 via `new Array(11).fill(0)` and use that as the `accumulator` for the reduce. Since the `date` key only affects 2 elements [indexes 7 and 10] the reduce will only update those leaving the rest as 0s to match the expected output.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This solution is the fastest so far. It doesn't speak for itself as `for-of-for-in` but anyway a good looking one. Haven't wrapped my head around `reduce()` in details yet though. :/

Comment: Thanks. Added more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can get code a little cleaner by removing large and hardly readable chained construction, and also by getting rid of this magic `8.64e7` number:

```js
function process(data)
{
  // get rid of weird object keys
  let eventsArray = data.map(x => Object.values(x)[0]); // [{ amount, timestamp }, { amount, timestamp }, ...]
  
  // convert timestamp to date
  eventsArray.forEach(x => { // [{ amount, timestamp, date }, { amount, timestamp, date }...]
    x.date = new Date(x.timestamp).toLocaleDateString(); // consider using something better
  }); 
  
  // group and sum by date
  let byDate = eventsArray.reduce((dic, x) => {
    dic[x.date] = dic[x.date] === undefined ? x.amount : dic[x.date] + x.amount;
    return dic;
  }, {});
  
  return byDate;
}

const input = [{
    LQsZ2cuD1n5U10Rhg9p: {
      amount: 14,
      timestamp: 1541768493811
    }
  },
  {
    LR6Bx6pih4TRID9i3LW: {
      amount: 24,
      timestamp: 1542014096044
    }
  },
  {
    LR6IbF4Q0SI9TZ6Sh5h: {
      amount: 34,
      timestamp: 1542015841476
    }
  },
  {
    LR6NLdgGd2UgTMpnYYE: {
      amount: 46,
      timestamp: 1542017084204
    }
  },
  {
    LR6R5ql8lJW_gTctXB6: {
      amount: 11,
      timestamp: 1542018068191
    }
  },
  {
    LR6R5v0ag8twyTjeupC: {
      amount: 12,
      timestamp: 1542018068351
    }
  },
  {
    LR6R5xZZ4VNCIud71MP: {
      amount: 16,
      timestamp: 1542018069574
    }
  },
  {
    LR6R5zz5QrvrM_RTrvT: {
      amount: 31,
      timestamp: 1542018069716
    }
  },
  {
    LR6R6Aser7lmvrGetzm: {
      amount: 21,
      timestamp: 1542018069996
    }
  },
];

console.log(process(input));
```

You can now fill in missing dates with 0 if you know the range of observed dates, or just pass it to a chart library, they usually can handle missing dates.

Comment: Thank you for a reply! Have added some visuals to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit more readable with for loops:

```js
const data = [ { LQsZ2cuD1n5U10Rhg9p: { amount: 14, timestamp: 1541768493811 } }, 
               { LR6Bx6pih4TRID9i3LW: { amount: 24, timestamp: 1542014096044 } }, 
               { LR6IbF4Q0SI9TZ6Sh5h: { amount: 34, timestamp: 1542015841476 } }, 
               { LR6NLdgGd2UgTMpnYYE: { amount: 46, timestamp: 1542017084204 } }, 
               { LR6R5ql8lJW_gTctXB6: { amount: 11, timestamp: 1542018068191 } }, 
               { LR6R5v0ag8twyTjeupC: { amount: 12, timestamp: 1542018068351 } }, 
               { LR6R5xZZ4VNCIud71MP: { amount: 16, timestamp: 1542018069574 } }, 
               { LR6R5zz5QrvrM_RTrvT: { amount: 31, timestamp: 1542018069716 } }, 
               { LR6R6Aser7lmvrGetzm: { amount: 21, timestamp: 1542018069996 } }, ];

const info = Array(11).fill(0);

for (let obj of data)
  for (let key in obj)
    info[Math.round((Date.now() - obj[key].timestamp) / 864e5)] += obj[key].amount;

console.log( JSON.stringify(info) );
```

[for...in statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to enumerate object keys.

[for...of statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) (new in ES6 and not supported in IE) to itterate over the values of array-like objects.

`Array(11)` by itself creates empty array object (without keys and values) with length 11, similar to :

```
const info = [];
info.length = 11;
```

That is why `.fill(0)` is used to populate it with 0 values.

Comment: Looks very very promising! Could you please elaborate those for-of and for-in loops a bit for those like me. Can't get the point why you sum `info[date] += amount` at the end?

Comment: Plus 1 for `Array(11).fill(0);`!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so probably the only bad thing about the way I have done this is that I take advantage of the fact that all of the days in the original array are close together. If you were going to implement this in your code, I would recommend taking some time to do a better job finding the difference in the number of days.

```
function reduce(array) {

        let resultArray = Array(11).fill(0);

        array.forEach(element => {
            var elementKey = Object.keys(element);
            var thisElement = element[elementKey];

            var date = new Date(thisElement.timestamp);
            var currentDate = new Date();

            var numOfDaysAgo = currentDate.getDate() - date.getDate();

            resultArray[numOfDaysAgo] += thisElement.amount;

        });

        return resultArray;

    }


    console.log(reduce(data));  //(11) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 195, 0, 0, 14]
```

Comment: Thank you for a reply! Your solution is not a laconic one I should say. I was looking for a short one-liner ideally but it looks like such manipulations might be performed with a help of libraries only. :/

Comment: No, but I'm the type of coder who prefers readability to brevity

Comment: I am more of `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'`

Comment: Also there are performance issues. It's 2 times slower than `reduce()` of @Akrion and `for-of-for-in` of @Slai. The slowest one is that first solution similar to yours. Interesting.

Comment: Maybe, but when you look at it someone who knows JavaScript can comprehend pretty easily what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: Agreed, that is the reason for sure to write more concisely.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative for enumerating the values during parsing :

```js
const json = '[{"LQsZ2cuD1n5U10Rhg9p":{"amount":140,"timestamp":1541768493811}},{"LR6Bx6pih4TRID9i3LW":{"amount":240,"timestamp":1542014096044}},{"LR6IbF4Q0SI9TZ6Sh5h":{"amount":340,"timestamp":1542015841476}},{"LR6NLdgGd2UgTMpnYYE":{"amount":460,"timestamp":1542017084204}},{"LR6R5ql8lJW_gTctXB6":{"amount":110,"timestamp":1542018068191}},{"LR6R5v0ag8twyTjeupC":{"amount":120,"timestamp":1542018068351}},{"LR6R5xZZ4VNCIud71MP":{"amount":160,"timestamp":1542018069574}},{"LR6R5zz5QrvrM_RTrvT":{"amount":310,"timestamp":1542018069716}},{"LR6R6Aser7lmvrGetzm":{"amount":210,"timestamp":1542018069996}}]'
const info = Array(11).fill(0);

JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => 
      v.amount ? info[Math.round((Date.now() - v.timestamp) / 8.64e7)] += v.amount : v)

console.log( JSON.stringify(info) );
```